# typescript-eslint error: no-angle-bracket-type-assertion

Tags: typescript, npm-start, typescript-eslint

Got this error while bootstrapping React App -

```
$ npm start
```

**Failed to compile.
./src/components/containers/Foo.tsx
  Line 1:  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion' was not found  @typescript-eslint/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.**

Assuming this to be a solution (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/863), I even removed 'eslintConfig' from package.json:

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
```

But it did not help. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your project must be on a very, very old version of typescript-eslint. That issue correctly mentions that the `'@typescript-eslint/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion'` rule was removed in 2.0.0 released August 13, 2019.

Make sure your packages are all on relatively recent versions. Ideally everything should be on the latest version, or at least on the latest major.minor version, or failing that at least the latest major version.

See also the getting started guide for angular-eslint: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#quick-start